# Can't Solve google scholar search picture CAPTCHA

Tags: google-search, google-scholar

I am using a script called Google Scholar Citation Explorer, its a nice script that allows one to search for scientific articles. However the newer versions of Google Chrome or Firefox does not work with it. I've resorted to using firefox version 3.6 which works.

However on firefox version 3.6 the reCAPTCHA does not work, so i am blocked from using google scholar.

[image]

Does anyone know a workaround? is there any way to use the keyboard to solve the reCAPTCHA?.

[image]

Comment: just use [brute force](http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solve-selenium-python/) to solve picture puzzle.

Comment: Thanks but, the mouse does not work. I really cannot click

Comment: in those examples brute force does not imply any real user interactions (incl. mouse clicks). You just leverage [iMacro](http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solved-imacros/) or Selenium scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Google Scholar Citation Explorer works on firefox version 15.0 
where the reCAPTCHA also works. Which I have detailed in [this youtube video:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdxF2YxQwfs)